# How to put the logged in users username in the URL using javascript?

Tags: javascript

Done alot of research, and haven't found anything helpful yet!.

My question is I would like to put the logged in users nickname in the URL using javascript?

EXAMPLE :

```
<a href="http://chat.mibbit.com/?server=irc.mibbit.net&channel=%23yourCh&nick=LOGGEDINUSERNICK" target="_blank">open a Chat window
```

I'll keep looking around. Can anyone help?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to put the username there using the server-side language?

Comment: Does it have to be JS? If you have Users on your site, you almost certainly have a server side language as well. You could do it this way: `<a href="http://chat.mibbit.com/?server=irc.mibbit.net&channel=%23yourCh&nick=<?php echo $_COOKIE['user']?>" target="_blank">open a Chat window</a>`

Comment: I'm a front end designer. I haven't the foggiest clue how that would work.  can you elaborate on the php? and is it possible with JS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you have users nickname defined somewhere. There are two cases: the href is already filled in and you just want to add the nickname, or you are creating the uri + nickname yourself.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/4FwHY/

HTML:

```
<a id="chat" href="http://chat.mibbit.com/?server=irc.mibbit.net&channel=%23yourCh&nick=" target="_blank">open a Chat window</a>
```

Script (your function in comments modified):

```
function toggle_visibility( id ) { 

    var url = 'http://widget.mibbit.com/?settings=46780594e96e435ff18e44e48b7d880d&amp;ser‌ver=irc.Mibbit.Net&amp;channel=%23yourCh&nick=',
        username = document.getElementsByClassName( 'user-nickname' )[0].innerText;
    document.getElementById( 'chat' ).setAttribute( 'href', url + username );

    var e = document.getElementById( id ); 

    if( e.style.visibility == 'hidden' ) {

        e.style.visibility = 'visible'; 

    } else {

        e.style.visibility = 'hidden'; 

    };

};
```

When focus leaves the input box, the url gets updated. So they could type their username, then click the link and it will work.

Comment: yes, the usernames are defined in the input fields they use. 

<input type=​"text" id=​"form-nickname" name=​"form-nickname" size=​"50" maxlength=​"128" rel=​"validate[required]​" class>​

the link URL always stays the same, but the user nick changes.

And I knew there was a way to do it with JS. thank you for your help! do i just replace the 'someuser' with 'form-nickname'?

Comment: Awesome. This fixes the problem i've been having, thanks a million! Will install later and let you know results. I'm off to bed!

Comment: unfortunately the solution only work if the chatrooms are open on the edit profile page for the user. LoL

Comment: Yeah, if you don't have access to 'form-nickname' you'll need to store it in a variable or some other way.

Comment: Whoa, idea! The network I have shows your name and user pic on the sidebar at all time. Is there a way to utilize this for the URL?

Comment: Yes, you could use `document.getElementsByClassName( 'user-nickname' )[0].innerHTML` to get the usernick. You'll need to set it from a different event though -- whatever is activating the chat.

Comment: using a simple toggle to open chatroom.

`<script type="text/javascript">

function resettoggle() {
var e = document.getElementById('foo');
e.style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
function toggle_visibility(id) {
var e = document.getElementById(id);
if(e.style.visibility == 'hidden')
e.style.visibility = 'visible';
else
e.style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
</script>`

Comment: `<a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('foo');"><img src="http://static.sgcdn.net/icons/lightbox-close.png" /></a>

<div id="foo" style="visibility:hidden; ">

<iframe height="450" src="http://widget.mibbit.com/?settings=46780594e96e435ff18e44e48b7d880d&amp;ser‌​ver=irc.Mibbit.Net&amp;channel=%23yourCh&nick=" style="width="750"></iframe>`

Comment: Put the code from inside the event in the answer into your `toggle_visibility` function or a function initializing your page.

Comment: Still won't get user nickname. My brain is frazzled, what am I missing? http://mibpaste.com/ZoBRCJ

Comment: Close! The user nickname is giving "undefined" for a name right now. Do we still need to retrieve? `document.getElementsByClassName( 'user-nickname' )[0].innerHTML`

Comment: Ooops. Yeah, use `document.getElementsByClassName( 'user-nickname' )[0].innerHTML`

Comment: GOT IT.. use .innerText for .innerHTML  IT WORK IT WORKS. awesome. thanks for everything!!!